# Is it possible to obtain a Swift type from a string?

Tags: swift, struct

I wonder if it's possible to obtain a Swift type dynamically. For example, say we have the following nested structs:

```
struct Constants {

  struct BlockA {
    static let kFirstConstantA = "firstConstantA"
    static let kSecondConstantA = "secondConstantA"
  }

 struct BlockB {    
    static let kFirstConstantB = "firstConstantB"
    static let kSecondConstantB = "secondConstantB"
  }

  struct BlockC {
    static let kFirstConstantC = "firstConstantBC"
    static let kSecondConstantC = "secondConstantC"
  }
}
```

It's possible to get value from kSeconConstantC from a variable). Like:

```
let variableString = "BlockC"
let constantValue = Constants.variableString.kSecondConstantC
```

Something akin to `NSClassFromString`, maybe?

Comment: value can not be used as identifier , as per my thinking i think it is not possible

Comment: you can use like if (variableString ==  "BlockC") then do something

Comment: Thanks for your commend but the idea behind is to reduce code. I would prefer a (if exists) a solution as I mentioned instead write several if-else for each case.

Comment: Theoretical alternative: uses classes and subclass `NSObject`, followed by setting/getting properties of the subtype by a combination of runtime introspection (`Mirror(...)`) and `NSObject`:s key value access. But same advice as luk2302 gives holds here as well; do not use such a solution in production.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not possible yet (as a language feature, at least).

What you need is your own **type registry**. Even with a type registry, you wouldn't be able to get `static` constants unless you had a protocol for that:

```
var typeRegistry: [String: Any.Type] = [:]

func indexType(type: Any.Type)
{
    typeRegistry[String(type)] = type
}

protocol Foo
{
    static var bar: String { get set }
}

struct X: Foo
{
    static var bar: String = "x-bar"
}

struct Y: Foo
{
    static var bar: String = "y-bar"
}

indexType(X)
indexType(Y)

typeRegistry // ["X": X.Type, "Y": Y.Type]

(typeRegistry["X"] as! Foo.Type).bar // "x-bar"
(typeRegistry["Y"] as! Foo.Type).bar // "y-bar"
```

A type registry is something that registers your types using a custom `Hashable` type (say a `String` or an `Int`). You can then use this type registry to reference registered types using custom identifiers (a `String`, in this case).

Since `Any.Type` by itself isn't all that useful, I constructed an interface `Foo` through which I could access a static constant `bar`. Because I know that `X.Type` and `Y.Type` both conform to `Foo.Type`, I forced a cast and read the `bar` property.

Comment: Cool!  Could you explain a little bit what's going on?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to follow that way.

Comment: This is neat, although note that if you know that the types in a given registry will always conform to a given protocol, you should make the registry `[String: Foo.Type]` in order to eliminate the smelly force downcasting.