# Something similar to NSClassFromString for structs in swift?

Tags: swift, struct

I want to know if I only know the name of a struct (in string format), how can I initialize it?

I know for classes this is possible using `NSClassFromString` as follows:

```
@objc(MyClass)
class MyClass: NSObject {
  var a: Int?
  var b: String?
}

let myClassType: NSObject.Type? = NSClassFromString("MyClass") as? NSObject.Type
let myClass = myClassType?.init() // this will be NSObject but in reality is MyClass
```

My question is, is there a way to do the similar thing for **structs**?

```
struct MyStruct {
  var a: Int
  var b: String
}
```

Comment: The short answer is no.  The long answer explains why.

Comment: @Avi what's the long answer? :)

Comment: I'm not sure why you would only have the name of the struct in string format, but I would suggest redesigning your code so that's not the case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to obtain a Swift type from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318897/is-it-possible-to-obtain-a-swift-type-from-a-string)